# Link to page sections from another part of my site

Tags: jquery, html, css

On a few of my pages I am using JQuery to show and hide different sections of content without refreshing the page.  Is there a way I can link to specific sections of a page from a global navigation?  Ultimately I want the user to click a link from a different page, and jump back to certain section on a different page.

I have an example of what I currently have here, http://jsfiddle.net/tjaymz/JUJf7/

```
<nav id="sideNav">
<ul class="noStyle">
    <li><a href="#" name="menu1">Line 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="menu2">Line 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="menu3">Line 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<section id="page_menu1">
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <p>FPO</p>
</section>

<section id="page_menu2" class="hidden">
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <p>FPO</p>
</section>

<section id="page_menu3" class="hidden">
    <h1>Another one</h1>
    <p>FPO</p>
</section>
```

```
$(function(){
$("#main_content section:not(:first-child)").hide();  //hide all but first
$("#sideNav a").click(function () {
    $('#main_content section').hide('fast');
    $('#page_'+this.name).show('normal');
});});
```

Using this example I need to link from another page to say "Line 2" from this example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use anchors for the section of the page in your site you want to link to. Make the link on your global nav go to the anchor and it should work.

Comment: I have tried that with no luck. Have tried, `<a href="page#page_menu2">` and that did not seem to work.

Comment: Unless you alter the default code, an anchor will move the window to the location of the anchor tag but it will not click the link for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

1. Write a little javascript to click the button pointed to by some parameter in the URI.
2. Separate your pages. Javascript is nice but if you use it too much, it can limit accessibility, hamper SEO, make links brittle, and so on. If you still like the javascript feel, you can render these separate pages through javascript, json, or xml when the server receives a `data-remote` request. Using AJAX in this sense is good because the site will keep functioning for every user and you won't end up having unforeseen issues because of your UX.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the url hash on page load. Try something along these lines:

```
$(function () {
    $("#main_content section").hide();

    var selected = $(window.location.hash);
    if (selected.length) {
        selected.show();
    } else {
        $("#main_content section:first-child").show();
    }
});
```

then if the user links in with `#page_url1` in their url, that section will be visible.

For a more comprehensive solution, you might want to look into something like [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Comment: Was pulled to a different thing for a few days, finally back to this! I tried your suggestion here, and it works great, except now my show/hide function for my sidebar nav no longer works.